# Android asmack received iq packets are formatted in wrong way

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am using asmack for implementing chat client application.
I am sending an IQ request for fetching previous chats. Though I get all previous chats some of them are broken. Actually output should be off following order:

```
<iq id="IQRequestPubSubItems" to="someid" from="example.com" type="result">
<pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
<items node='some_node_id'>
<item id='55812E6AAF0EB'>
<entry xmlns="mcn:panel">
<body>New image</body>
<imagename>file.6</imagename>
<file name="public-380" type="image/jpg"/>
<published jid="some_id" datetime="2013-05-09T05:30:18Z"/>
</item>
```

But I am getting response as follows:

```
<iq id="IQRequestPubSubItems" to="someid" from="example.com" type="result">
<pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
<items node='some_node_id'>
<item id='55812E6AAF0EB'>
<body>New image</body>
<imagename>file.6</imagename>
<file name="public-380" type="image/jpg"/>
</item>
<published xmlns="mcn:panel">
</published>
```

Iam using asmack6 on Android API 17.
When checked on server they are sending it correctly. Also when I enabled debug on aSmack I see that it receives proper message but when I get the Packet in my Android app's PacketListener it gets broken.

Comment: Did you try the latest aSmack version?

Comment: yeah...but all the jar versions has this issue..Is it possible to catch the packets as raw..we can saw then while debugging...

Comment: Where does the `<file name="public-380" type="image/jpg"/>` element come from? You should attach an debugger and retrace the parsing of the IQ provider for this stanza. Maybe this will give you some insight on what is going on here.

Comment: Sorry, <file name="public-380" type="image/jpg"/> is received in both cases, I just missed that in my question